# only display value if input value is greater than 0

Tags: javascript, php, html, loops

So I have hit a wall. I am trying to avoid displaying all the color options from a form in a "review order" page.
So they would enter desired quantity in the form for each color and submit to review.php page.
I'm just not sure if I need a PHP loop or a javascript loop or how to accomplish this.
Any help is really appreciated!

Form

```
<form action="review.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
<p>12x12<br>
c000x12 <input type="text" name="c000x12"><br>
c010x12 <input type="text" name="c010x12"><br>
c020x12 <input type="text" name="c020x12"><br>
c019x12 <input type="text" name="c019x12"><br>
c021x12 <input type="text" name="c021x12"><br>
</p>
<p>12x24<br>
c000x24 <input type="text" name="c000x24"><br>
c010x24 <input type="text" name="c010x24"><br>
c020x24 <input type="text" name="c020x24"><br>
c019x24 <input type="text" name="c019x24"><br>
c021x24 <input type="text" name="c021x24">
</p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"></p>

</form>
```

Then on the review page I have the following...
And I would like to only display the values that are greater than 0.

PHP

```
<?PHP

// x12
$c000x12= $_POST["c000x12"];
$c010x12= $_POST["c010x12"];
$c020x12= $_POST["c020x12"];
$c019x12= $_POST["c019x12"];
$c021x12= $_POST["c021x12"];

// x24
$c000x24= $_POST["c000x24"];
$c010x24= $_POST["c010x24"];
$c020x24= $_POST["c020x24"];
$c019x24= $_POST["c019x24"];
$c021x24= $_POST["c021x24"];

?>
```

HTML

```
<p>12x12<br>
<? echo "000 Transparent=".$c000x12 ."<br/>".
"010 White=".$c010x12 ."<br/>".
"020 Golden yellow=".$c020x12 ."<br/>".
"019 Signal yellow=".$c019x12 ."<br/>".
"021 Yellow=".$c021x12 ."<br/>" ; ?>
</p>
<p>12x24<br>
<? echo "000 Transparent=".$c000x24 ."<br/>".
"010 White=".$c010x24 ."<br/>".
"020 Golden yellow=".$c020x24 ."<br/>".
"019 Signal yellow=".$c019x24 ."<br/>".
"021 Yellow=".$c021x24 ."<br/>" ; ?>
</p>
```

Comment: Could you please explain more simpler way so I can help out?

Comment: I dont actually know what problem you are trying to solve, please edit your question to make your question clearer

Comment: @RiggsFolly well as it is now, if the client only wants 10 of a single color and size, the review page will still display ALL the results including the zero or blank values.
I would like to omit those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to only display the values that are greater than 0.

The solution using `array_filter` and `implode` functions:

***PHP:***

```
$c12x12 = array_filter([$c000x12, $c010x12, $c019x12, $c020x12, $c021x12], function ($v) {
    return (int) $v > 0;
});

$c12x24 = array_filter([$c000x24, $c010x24, $c020x24, $c019x24, $c021x24], function ($v) {
    return (int) $v > 0;
});
```

---

***HTML:***

```
<p>12x12<br>
<?php echo implode('<br>', $c12x12); ?>
</p>
<p>12x24<br>
<?php echo implode('<br>', $c12x24); ?>
</p>
```

Comment: okay so its getting it into an array so I can check it.
Im going to try this.
I edited the code to display the "color = #"
Is that still possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think I might reserve the use of a loop to a case where the values were each being pushed to an array.

That said, and working within this setup I might recommend something like this for the display:

```
<p>12x12<br> 
<?php if( $c000x12 > 0 ){ echo $c000x12 ."<br>" }; ?>
<?php if( $c010x12 > 0 ){ echo $c010x12 ."<br>" }; ?>
<?php if( $c020x12 > 0 ){ echo $c020x12 ."<br>" }; ?>
<?php if( $c019x12 > 0 ){ echo $c019x12 ."<br>" }; ?>
<?php if( $c021x12 > 0 ){ echo $c021x12 ."<br>" }; ?>
</p>

<p>12x24<br> 
<?php if( $c000x24 > 0 ){ echo $c000x24 ."<br>" }; ?>
<?php if( $c010x24 > 0 ){ echo $c010x24 ."<br>" }; ?>
<?php if( $c020x24 > 0 ){ echo $c020x24 ."<br>" }; ?>
<?php if( $c019x24 > 0 ){ echo $c019x24 ."<br>" }; ?>
<?php if( $c021x24 > 0 ){ echo $c021x24 ."<br>" }; ?>
</p>
```

An array approach example:

```
<?php

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
 if($value > 0){
  echo $value . "</br>";
 }
};

?>
```

Comment: I see how this might work but some products have 50+ colors and 2 sizes so that would be 100 lines to code that way.
I mean if I have to I can but I thought a loop of some sort might be better.

Comment: Ah yeah, I was just trying to mimic the HTML/PHP structure from your example. One sec, and I'll give a loop a go.

Comment: Added example, may need some tweaking for your visual needs @JamesCrellin

Comment: Cool. I will try that too.

Answer (score 0):

I really want to thank you guys for the help. I got a fix in place. I used the array_filter and foreach loop from both answers.
I forgot to mention in the OP that I needed the names displayed as well. However, after the tips here and more research, here is my fix.

**note.. all the variables in the QTY sections will be $_POST from the form.

FORM remains the same...

REVIEW

```
<?php
// COLORS
$n000= "Transparent";
$n010= "White";
$n020= "Black";
$n019= "Red";
$n021= "Blue";
//x12 QTY
$c000x12= "8";
$c010x12= "2";
$c020x12= "";
$c019x12= "1";
$c021x12= "3";
//x24 QTY
$c000x24= "0";
$c010x24= "1";
$c020x24= "3";
$c019x24= "0";
$c021x24= "9";



$x12=array($n000=>$c000x12,$n010=>$c010x12,$n020=>$c020x12,$n019=>$c019x12,$n021=>$c021x12);

echo "<b>12 x 12</b> <br>";

foreach($x12 as $clr=>$qty) {
 if($qty > 0){
  echo $clr . " = " . $qty;
  echo "<br>";
 }
};

  echo "<br>";

$x24=array($n000=>$c000x24,$n010=>$c010x24,$n020=>$c020x24,$n019=>$c019x24,$n021=>$c021x24);

echo "<b>12 x 24</b> <br>";

foreach($x24 as $clr=>$qty) {
 if($qty > 0){
  echo $clr . " = " . $qty;
  echo "<br>";
 }
};
?>
```

And this will output...

**12 x 12** 
Transparent = 8
White = 2
Red = 1
Blue = 3
**12 x 24** 
White = 1
Black = 3
Blue = 9